# How to convert temp table with case statement SQL to Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm very newbie in Linq and don't know how to solve some problems even very easy in MS SQL query.

```
Select e.EmployeeID
, e.EmployeeName
, e.Division
, e.DepartmentCode
, e.DesignationGrpCode
Into #temp
from chr.dbo.EMPLOYEE e
Where e.DepartmentCode in ( 
                        Select DepartmentCode 
                        from chr.dbo.EMPLOYEE 
                        where EmployeeID = 'S-1287'
                        )

Select * from #temp t
where t.EmployeeID in (
                        Case When t.Division <> 'CHR' Then (Select EmployeeID from #temp where DesignationGrpCode = 'CorpDMGR')
                        Else (Select EmployeeID from #temp where DesignationGrpCode = 'MGT') End)
Drop table #temp
```

How do I convert this query to Linq? Please

here is my linq statement

```
var employee = new Common().Employee();

        var jobdesc = new Common().JobHistory();

        List<EMPLOYEE> dCode = (from e in employee
                              where e.EmployeeID == "S-1204"
                              select new EMPLOYEE
                              {
                                  DepartmentCode = e.DepartmentCode
                              }).ToList();

        List<EMPLOYEE> emp = (from e in employee
           join d in dCode on e.DepartmentCode equals d.DepartmentCode into temp
           from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()


           orderby e.EmployeeName
           select new EMPLOYEE
           {
               EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
               EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName
           }).ToList();
```

but dun know how to check CASE ELSE statement

Comment: Please add the LINQ that you made and didn't do what you were after.

Comment: @Bazzz Hi please check, it has been updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a go. It compiles and runs in [ideone](http://ideone.com/5DXdgt), but is otherwise untested, so good luck.

```
var temp = from e in context.EMPLOYEE
           where (from f in context.EMPLOYEE
                  where f.EmployeeID == "S-1287"
                  && e.DepartmentCode == f.DepartmentCode
                  select f).Any()
           select e;

var result = from t in temp
             where (from u in temp
                    where u.DesignationGrpCode
                          == (t.Division == "CHR" ? "CorpDMGR" : "MGT")
                    && t.EmployeeID == u.EmployeeID
                    select u).Any()
             select t;
```

Assuming you're pointing to SQL Server 2005 or above, I'm hoping that LINQ is smart enough to turn the temp table into a WITH clause.

**UPDATE:** Since `temp`'s subquery almost certainly returns a single value, you should (assuming EmployeeID is the primary key) separate it out:

```
string deptForS1287 = (from e in context.EMPLOYEE
                       where e.EmployeeID == "S-1287"
                       select DepartmentCode).Single();

var temp = from e in context.EMPLOYEE
           where e.DepartmentCode == deptForS1287
           select e;

⋮
```

This has the side benefit of throwing an exception if the EMPLOYEE table doesn't mention employee S-1287.

Comment: Hi bro, your code looks like work perfectly and I used this, there has no error but no data comes out. really confused one! do u have any idea bro?

Comment: @CMMaung: Break it down into smaller parts. Start by checking whether `temp` has anything in it. If so, check whether `result`'s subquery has data, and so on. If not, then check whether `temp`'s subquery returns anything.

Comment: @CMMaung: I just realised a typo in the original query. The `temp` subquery matched on `EmployeeID` where it should have matched on `DepartmentCode`. I fix it and added a possible improvement.

Comment: thanks for your kindly help. Now I know why the previous one return no records. Because it returns only single value as you mentioned. Now got it! Thanks again. You make my day :)

Answer (score 1):

In an extreme case, you can do it:

```
using (var context = new ConnectDb())    
    {
         context.ExecuteStoreCommand("your query");
         // for exaple: context.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Peoples"); 
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: There's no LINQ in your answer. This is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Rim4irok thanks for your information. Seems like one of the solution :D